# How to resolve a non-jar (dll/jnilib) library dependencies in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

In a SBT `build.sbt` project file, is it possible to retrieve library dependencies which are not bundled as `jar`?

In my case, I am trying to use [QTSampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/qtsampledsp/index.html) which requires `.dll` and `.jnilib` libraries.

Comment: see sample code at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/master/project/NativeLibs.scala but it's a bit kludgy and the pathname manipulation parts are specific to our project. offering this hoping someone else will respond with something better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To download the artifact, you need to make *Ivy* (and hence sbt) explicitly aware of the DLL artifact. Add the following to `build.sbt` in your project.

```
lazy val QtSampledJniLibArt = Artifact("qtsampledsp-osx", "jnilib", "jnilib")

libraryDependencies += "com.tagtraum" % "qtsampledsp-osx" % "0.9.6" artifacts(QtSampledJniLibArt)

resolvers += "beatunes" at "http://www.beatunes.com/repo/maven2"
```

Then you need to tell sbt to pay attention to these artifacts (again `build.sbt`):

```
classpathTypes ++= Set("jnilib", "dll")
```

By default, sbt will only add a few types into the classpath (and `jnilib` and `dll` are not amongst them).

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> help classpathTypes
Artifact types that are included on the classpath.
[sbt-0-13-1]> show classpathTypes
[info] Set(eclipse-plugin, bundle, hk2-jar, orbit, jar)
```

Since these DLLs/jnilibs are needed on the classpath to run correctly, the above setting `classpathTypes` where you add the additional types will correct things as you can see below (don't forget to `reload` when in sbt console).

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> show classpathTypes
[info] Set(eclipse-plugin, bundle, hk2-jar, jnilib, orbit, jar, dll)
```

If you need to look in more detail at these files, check out the update report (from the `update` task) where you can inspect all configurations/modules/artifacts. Run `show update` in sbt console and look at the files in `target/resolution-cache/reports`.

Comment: Nice edits!  I always forget to mention where to add code :).

Comment: I'm always glad to help and I'm so much better in edits than writing answers myself. Keep them coming and mine will follow :)