# Referencing RocksDB DLL in SBT

Tags: windows, sbt, rocksdb

I am using RocksDB in a scala project with SBT.
For windows I understand that I need to infor SBT about the win64 DLL which is inside the jar file, but am still not getting this right.

I have tried what us written here but with no luck

[How to resolve a non-jar (dll/jnilib) library dependencies in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842311/how-to-resolve-a-non-jar-dll-jnilib-library-dependencies-in-sbt)

How do I use RocksDB in a windows Java project?

Comment: Issue is most prob missing windows dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly tell SBT about the Native Library (DLL on Windows) and the Rocks Jar file includes the Native Library and the startup code of RocksDB knows how to load that from the Jar.

Just include the RocksDB jar dependency (which includes the DLL) in your SBT build file as you would any other Java library.

Comment: What are the required dependencies? I too have been looking at this and had issues with dependencies. I saw this one https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/1329 but still not got it working

Comment: Actually my issue was not related... Issue was that I was running from within IntelliJ which is 32 bits, so the check for 64bit architecture was failing. Running from SBT on command line works as expected.

Comment: My problem running on Windows from intelliJ was not the OS (which is 64 bit) but that I was using 32bit JDK.
The OS check requires JDK 64bit to be used.

Comment: RocksDB does not support 32bit Windows.

Comment: I think more accurately 32 bit JVM. You may be running 64 bit windows with 32 bit JVM and this will also fail (at least in the version from about 2 months ago)